# How to implement promise to creating new popup window or make a call back?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I am creating a popup, in the popup i would like to add my `html` content in to one of the `div`.

new if i try like this, I am getting empty popup:

```
printPage = function (printData,printTemp,params) {
        var template = _.template(printTemp);
        var popWindow = window.open("js/Print/PrintLayout.html", "My PopUp", "width=900, height=700");

popWindow.document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = template(printData); // not appending!
    };
```

so I tried to adding the setTimeout to add the content like this way:

```
printPage = function (printData,printTemp,params) {
        var template = _.template(printTemp);
        var popWindow = window.open("js/Print/PrintLayout.html", "My PopUp", "width=900, height=700");

        setTimeout(function(){ // added setTime out
            popWindow.document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = template(printData);
        },50)
        // console.log('print works' + template(printData));
    };
```

It works fine. But I am sure the way what i do is wrong!
how can i get a call back from pop-up window, so that let me append the content after the popup created or what would be the correct approach to append a content in to a popup?

any help please?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You're probably looking for `window.onload`

Comment: My requirement is, I would like to trigger a call back or a promise type to append my content to pop-up, after the pop-up created all..